# Plotting Stacked Barplot Seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a df but it is multi indexed based on customer and commodity type but can't figure out the right way to plot

```py
aggregation_functions = {'Drawn': 'sum'}
out2 = out.groupby(['Customer','Commodity']).aggregate(aggregation_functions)
out2.head(10)
```

[image: df1]

I also have another df like this:

[image: df2]

And so I'm building a plot here:

```py
sns.set_context(context="poster", font_scale=2, rc={"axes.labelsize":50,'font.size': 40.0})
ax = sns.barplot(CustTonnes.nlargest(20,'Drawn'), x="Drawn", y = "Customer", errorbar=None, fill=True, legend=True)
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.1f',padding=2)
```

[image: Plot1]

But I would like to colour the bars based on the commodity type looking something like this:

[image: Example_Plot]

Comment: The easiest way is to use pivot (one value per category) or pivot table (multiple values per category): `dfp = df2.pivot(index='Customer', columns='Commodity', values='Drawn')` and then `ax = dfp.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`. Seaborn barplot does not do stacked bars. Also, it is better to not stack bars, especially if there's move than two color categories, because it's difficult to discern size.